# How to find object in container by value, not key

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

I have a `map` with `<int, int*>`

I want to search the `map` for a **specific value (not key)** and retrieve the iterator that points to the correct `int*` (value of the map)

Can I use the `std::find_if()` ?

```
auto it = std::find_if(map.begin(), map.end(), compare);
```

where the compare should be something like:

```
bool compare(int* v1, int* v2)
{
 return (v1==v2);
}
```

**What is the best way to acomplish this?**

Comment: `std::find_if` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/

Comment: What about [Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) ?

Comment: If you're doing this with any regularity, I'd strongly consider taking @LeFlou's suggestion instead of the current answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <string>                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::string> m = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}};
    std::string value_to_find = "b";
    auto it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [&](decltype(m)::value_type &v) {
        return v.second == value_to_find;
    });

    if (it != m.end()) {
        std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of `decltype()` you may directly use template instance:

```
[&](std::map<int, std::string>::value_type &v)
```

Comment: or with C++14, `[&](auto& v){...}`

Comment: @Creris yes, but the question is tagged with `c++11`. I really appreciate `c++14`'s auto type deduction.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, probably, confused with something. I was just mean, that it is inefficient to use with unordered containers.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy the time-complexity of your solution is still linear as `std::find_if` is fundamentally a linear time algorithm. You would need to use an algorithm that expects an ordered range if you wanted to achieve sub-linear time complexity.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy don't see how it's more efficient with ordered containers; ordered containers order on the key, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

`std::find_if` will do the job for any 'map-like' type, e.g. `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. Note the collection does **not** need to be ordered; anything that defines an `InputIterator` (i.e. is 'iterable') will do.

Here is a function that will work for anything 'map-like' (but not 'multimap-like')

```
template <typename MapType>
typename MapType::const_iterator find_value(const MapType& map, const typename MapType::mapped_type& value)
{
    return std::find_if(std::cbegin(map), std::cend(map), [&value] (const auto& p) { return p.second == value; });
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    std::unordered_map<int, char> map {{0, 'A'}, {1, 'B'}, {2, 'C'}};
    char val {'B'};
    auto it = find_value(map, val);
    if (it != std::cend(map)) std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You should be aware that this is a linear-time algorithm (regardless of whether the map is ordered or not), and thus if this is an operation you will be using a lot, you should consider if it would be better to just store the inverse mappings too.

Comment: You are using `auto` in lamba's argument list while this question is about `c++11`.